# Explanation: Ajax on for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ajax isn't working on a for loop. Can someone correct my code and please explain it to me. I just want to put those value on my database. I can only make it work if I call ajax once not like this, it is in a for loop.

```
var counter = $("input[name^= 'quantity']").length;
var array1 = $("input[name^= 'quantity']");
var array2 = $("input[name^= 'unit']");
var array3 = $("input[name^= 'item_description']");
var array4 = $("input[name^= 'stock_no']");
var array5 = $("input[name^= 'eunitcost']");
var array6 = $("input[name^= 'ecost']");

var i;

for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/pm/admin/service/user-service.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      operation: 'pr-items',
      pr_no: $('#prno').val(),
      quantity: array1.eq(i).val(),
      unit: array2.eq(i).val(),
      item_description: array3.eq(i).val(),
      stock_no: array4.eq(i).val(),
      eunitcost: array5.eq(i).val(),
      ecost: array6.eq(i).val
    },

    success: function(data) {
      alert('pr items success');
      //todo
    },
    error: function(data) {
      // alert('pr items error');
      //todo
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: In what specific way is this failing?  What's the actual problem?

Comment: Ideally you should only send in one AJAX request. Avoid looping and making an AJAX request for each record. Build an array and encode it as JSON.

Comment: @PeterFestejo: You are missing some `()` after `val` in your `ecost` line. Does that help?

Comment: Try setting async:false in your ajax call

Comment: "my code isn't working" with no explanation of what "working" means. What is your desired result? What specifically is not working? Without that information, this question is off-topic and should be closed

Comment: @Sanjay: That is *terrible* advice.  And is likely to stop working in browsers soon if it hasn't already.

Comment: @David I wish I could upvote your comment a thousand times.

Comment: @interfect well that works. But when i run it again it alert 'pr item error' when i remove the comment on it.

Comment: @PeterFestejo: If the AJAX operation is invoking the `error` callback then the server is returning an error.  What is that error?  Use your browser's debugging tools to observe the actual requests being sent to the server and the actual responses coming from the server.  Check your server-side application's logs for error information.  You need to *debug* to see what's happening.

Comment: Don't waste your time on this code because it is terrible performance-wise, learn how to pass a single array in a single request to the server

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the reason why my code above isnt working because `ecost: array6.eq(i).val` doesnt have a `()` after the `.val` and also I found out that this is not a good practice that having a ajax calls on loops. Im sorry if I can't explain well here in stackoverflow that resulting on downvotes and having a temporary ban. But well I deserve it. I just can't improve my questions.